# How do I use predictors/independent variables with different types in a regression algorthim?

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, dataset, partial-least-squares

I want to predict properties of a physical system (e.g.  dimension,
weigth, number of items) based on a set of known attributes for
the system. I have a good, large database of executed systems together with a catalogue of many properties for the systems.

Yet I am not sure which attributes are best and orthogonal to each other, that's why I decided to try Partial LeastSquare Regression.

But the choice of attributes and data types is 
wide, I have discrete categories ("A", "B", …) , continous (float)
variables  within limits (e.g. ambient temperature), booleans,
integers etc.  What is the best practice to implement a regression
with such a bucket of different independent variables? Map everything
into normalized floats?

Actually, I have to use multiple mulitvariate regression as the
dependent variable is a vector. It also consists of integers and
floats. So the question relates also to the output result.

Comment: For discrete variables, you can always use one-hot-encoding. For booleans, you can use simply use 0 for false and 1 for true (or vice-versa). For integers, there is nothing to be done since they are usable as is.

Comment: For the output, same logic applies. Discrete variables can again be coded to 1 and 0 for each level. However, when you want to predict a discrete variable, one way is to choose the column, which refers to a level, having highest value. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218125/are-pls-da-and-pls-lda-the-same or you can search for one-hot-encoding.